# Mount /var/logs as tmpfs, with help of overlayfs to save changes sometimes

Tags: logs, tmpfs, overlayfs, union-mount

Instead of just mounting tmpfs on `/var/log` I want to use overlayfs.

1. /var/log are writable tmpfs, but containing files were there before
   tmpfs mount. This old files are not in memory of tmpfs but in lower layer.
2. only changes are stored in tmpfs, while old and unmodified files
   stored on SSD
3. sometimes it should be possible to write changes to SSD, for example
   via cron. This should free up tmpfs memory

So, result should be: logs written to RAM, old and new boot logs accesable via same path. Changes are written sometimes to disk, by script.

Point is to speed up a little, and safe SSD from many writes.

(*I saw similar thing in puppy linux, not for logs, but for all changes to root*, but without installing it can't do the same, documentation not helps)

I will do same for browser cookies/cache based on answer. But persistent write will be done on browser close. Can't turn off browser cache, need at least small cache to have same bugs in my web development as users can have because of cache.

Comment: "_Point is to speed up a little, and save SSD from many writes._" All you're really doing is reimplementing the disk cache layer.

Comment: @roaima still it's an excellent idea for Raspberry Pi , Orange Pi etc. Where a power cut can corrupt your micro SD card turning your system unusable unless you have a protection like an overlay filesystem on some directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to make /var/log overlay, it shows SSD log files, and changes. All changes are kept in RAM. Later I'll do syncing, so changes become permanent every hour, by copying upper layer to lower.

```
#prepare layers
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=512m,mode=0775 tmpfs /var/log.tmpfs
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs/upper
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs/work
sudo chown -R root:syslog /var/log.tmpfs
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX /var/log.tmpfs

#prepare overlay
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.overlay
sudo chown root:syslog /var/log.overlay
sudo chmod u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX /var/log.overlay

#start overlay
sudo mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/var/log,upperdir=/var/log.tmpfs/upper,workdir=/var/log.tmpfs/work overlay /var/log.overlay
sudo mount --bind /var/log.overlay /var/log
```

To make changes persistent, its needed to unmount bind /var/log, copy files, then bind again.

Comment: why?  what actual benefit do you gain from this?  quickly fill up your RAM to trigger the kernel's OOM random-process-killer faster?

Comment: Max size of tmpfs is set, so ram will not fill up. `logrotate` configs are tuned the way it never fill all reserved size. Anyway, I find out its not possible to make changes persistent online, so I have to deceide either remove this script or loose logs on reboot. **This is normal for development server, not production.**

Comment: I still don't get what you were trying to achieve.  Where's the benefit?  there's certainly no performance benefit.  It just seems like extra complication and fragility for no good reason.   Probably qualifies as some form of premature optimisation: maybe something like "ram disks are fast so i'll put my logs on a tmpfs" without testing whether there's any actual, noticeable benefit. Hint: unless the logs are fsynced on every write, writes will be buffered anyway.

Comment: SSD have large buffer it self, I just don't want that unnecessary writes. Ok, I get your point. Will not recommend it somebody, but stay with it for myself :)

Comment: Please remember to accept your own answer.

Comment: My answer isn't perfect. Today there are new answer, I`ll check it later.

Comment: This is an excellent solution for a Raspberry Pi that loses power often and is subject to disk corruption if the SD card is writing while power is lost. Several key directories must be overlaid in addition to /var/log, but this solution lays the groundwork for creating a stable, read-only with ephemeral read/write support.

Comment: The solution might not be perfect but the thinking behind is brilliant

Comment: @LeonidMew your idea is excellent! I will apply as #Bred Hein mention to my SOC board to prevent SD card corruption when an event of power cut happens.

Answer (score 6):

While the accepted answer by LeonidMew is almost perfect, I would like to contribute a way to persist changes without the need to remount.

```
# prepare layers
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=512m,mode=0775 tmpfs /var/log.tmpfs
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs/upper
sudo mkdir -p /var/log.tmpfs/work
sudo chown -R root:syslog /var/log.tmpfs
sudo chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX /var/log.tmpfs

# create a bind mount to the parent directory of the log folder
# since mount --bind does not mount recursively when used on the
# parent, we can use this to preserve access to the real /var/log
# on the disk
sudo mkdir -p /tmp/realvar
sudo mount --bind /var /tmp/realvar

# mount overlay using this new mountpoint as lowerdir
sudo mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/realvar/log,upperdir=/var/log.tmpfs/upper,workdir=/var/log.tmpfs/work overlay /var/log
```

With this method /tmp/realvar/log is used as the lowerdir and remains accessible even while the overlay is mounted. We can use this mountpoint to synchronize changes:

```
sudo rsync -vaz --delete /var/log/ /tmp/realvar/log
```

Thanks LeonidMew for the great idea. This concept is very useful for Raspberry Pis to reduce the write cycles on the SD card while still preserving most of the logs in case of an accidental power loss.

Comment: Excelent! [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/29656/does-a-mountpoint-have-to-be-an-empty-directory/29657#29657) helped understand that `mount` on a non empty folder 'hides' its contents and the `bind` is just 'unhiding' it somewhere else to make it usable as `lowerdir`.

Comment: Nice one, but can we do the same to remount `/` as overlayfs, because you cannot create a realroot relative to / as its going to be remounted, is there a way to refer to previous mount in that case?

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest anything-sync-daemon. It pretty good job.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/anything-sync-daemon

From the documentation,

> anything-sync-daemon (asd) is a tiny pseudo-daemon designed to manage user specified directories referred to as sync targets from here on out, in tmpfs and to periodically sync them back to the physical disc (HDD/SSD). This is accomplished via a symlinking step and an innovative use of rsync to maintain synchronization between a tmpfs copy and media-bound backups. Additionally, asd features several crash recovery features.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize flash drive writes, I'm using [log2ram](https://github.com/azlux/log2ram), and it works really well. It syncs to the flash drive on a schedule I supply