# Mounting Overlay File System and Using rsync to sync changes doesn't work for me

Tags: raspberry-pi, overlayfs, mmc

I'm working on an embedded application using Raspberry Pi CM4 running DietPi OS.  I want to minimize MMC flash writes as much as possible for maximum lifespan.  In my installation, there are a few applications frequently writing data throughout the /var directory (not just to the usual offenders of /var/log and /var/tmp).  This new data in /var is not mission critical so I want to mount all of /var as an overlayfs and then have a shutdown script to synchronize changes to the disk one time.  I have the overlay part working fine.  Here is my startup script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Startup script to mount /var as an overlay to minimize eMMC writes

if mount | grep "overlay on /var type overlay"; then
  echo Mount Point at /var already exists, exiting.
  exit 1
else
  if [ ! -d "/var.tmpfs" ]
  then
     mkdir -p /var.tmpfs
  fi
  mount -t tmpfs -o rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=256m,mode=0775 tmpfs /var.tmpfs
  mkdir -p /var.tmpfs/upper
  mkdir -p /var.tmpfs/work
  chown -R root:root /var.tmpfs
  chmod -R u=rwX,g=rwX,o=rX /var.tmpfs
  if [ ! -d "/tmp/realvar" ]
  then
   mkdir -p /tmp/realvar
  fi
  mount --bind /var /tmp/realvar
  sudo mount -t overlay -o rw,lowerdir=/tmp/realvar,upperdir=/var.tmpfs/upper,workdir=/var.tmpfs/work overlay /var
fi
exit 0
```

This results in zero MMC writes to anything written to /var while still having use of the data being written there using the overlayfs.  The hard part is working well.  Now I want to synchronize updates in the upperdir to disk to survive a planned reboot/shutdown event.  I realize a power loss event will cost me all the data in upperdir and that is fine.

Synchronization script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Shutdown script to sync the contents of the temporary overlay to actual /var on disk

if [ -d "/tmp/realvar" ]
  then
    rsync -vaz --delete /var/ /tmp/realvar
fi
exit 0
```

Credit for most of the above goes to LeonidMew and Tobby Fox from this very relevant but older thread: [Mount /var/logs as tmpfs, with help of overlayfs to save changes sometimes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424341)

Here's the issue: the rsync doesn't work and I cannot figure out why.  To test, I create a file in /var/lib after the overlay is established.  I then execute my rsync command string which appears to execute as expected.  I reboot and my test file is gone.  In other words, the contents of the upperdir are not being written to disk the way I want them to be.

An interesting observation: After creating my test file in /var/lib, it exists instantly in /var.tmpfs/upper/lib and in /tmp/realvar/lib also.  I do not expect it in /tmp/realvar/lib as this is the "lower" directory of the overlay.  Not sure if this is related but it is an odd thing I noticed.

I use the command below to confirm my overlay is actually working by observing all my apps reading/writing to the /var overlay and confirming the result of this command does not change:

```
cat /sys/fs/ext4/mmcblk0p2/lifetime_write_kbytes
```

All changes in /var are lost after reboot since my rsync function is not working.  With the overlay on /var and the minimalist install I have with DietPi, there are zero MMC writes after boot yet if I change a setting in /etc or change my embedded application in /usr then it gets written instantly and survives a reboot.  If I can just get this rsync of the /var overlay to work then I will have a perfect (for me) embedded filesystem configuration.

Any thoughts would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Related - [Merge changes to upper filesystem to lower filesystem in Linux Overlay (OverlayFS) mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/393930/100397)